# undefined method `path' for "test.csv":String Did you mean? pathmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-csv

While importing csv I'm facing this issue

```
`def self.import(file)
    binding.pry
    CSV.new(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    puts "upload"
    end     
end`
```

Comment: in your case `file` is not a file, its a String

Comment: may I know why is this happening.